# Distribute ipad apps without apple deployment process

Tags: ios, ipad

Is another way to distribute ipad application to corporate iPad users without having to go through the Apple deployment process?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could take a look at one of the Ad-Hoc sites like [testflight.com](https://www.testflightapp.com/), otherwise you need an [enterprise dev license](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). In that case it is however illegal to distribute the app outside the company

Note that you are limited to 100 devices if you choose the Ad-Hoc mode, but it's a very easy approch for both users and developers.

Answer (score 0):

If it is within one company, you can become an [enterprise developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).  If you just want to distribute them to everyone while thumbing your nose at Apple, then your only choice is to hand over your source and have everyone compile it.